# Accessing private ip inside docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a code written which uses the private ip, i have created a docker image of it. But while running the image, it is not able to access the my ip, Is there any way where we can map docker container with my private ip?

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example?  Typically Docker manages your containers' networks itself and you never think about IP addresses directly.  At least knowing what that IP address belongs to (another container on the same host, or on another host, or another host on the same network, or over a VPN, or ...) would be helpful.

Comment: How do you launch docker? Do you try to access your IP from inside or outside container? From where you want to access it? Please edit and explain it clearly with commands you've executed

Comment: Your code should be able to reach outside IP address if your host can. What error you get from inside container when try to access IP?

Comment: @DavidMaze, My ip is 192.168.1.4(this is private ip in my network). This ip i'm using in my code to get the data. When I'm creating docker image and running the image, it is giving error as not able to logon to this(192.168.1.4) server. My doubt is can we access the ip of our private network from docker?

Comment: @mulg0r , I'm trying to access my private ip inside docker container. I want to access my private ip from docker image. Since docker runs on another network, my code is not able to access that ip (192.169.1.4).

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things:

1. Try to access `host.docker.internal` from inside container.
   Just replace your `192.168.1.4` by `host.docker.internal`
2. Launch docker with `--net=host` and use `localhost` instead `192.168.1.4`